# Error al conectar SQL Server con Python mediante pyodbc

Tags: python, sql

Utilizando el siguiente codigo:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    "Driver = {SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
    "Server = CAETA-PC\SQLEXPRESS;"
    "Database = Datos_Sistema;"
    "Trusted_Connection = yes;"
)
```

me arroja este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo creado un origen de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el nombre del servidor con autenticacion de windows es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: donde dice driver no seria como nombre "conexion"?

Comment: Lo probe, pero me sigue dando error

Comment: hay algo raro ahi.. server y database ya estan adentro de la conexion ODBC.. estas seguro que los campos para conectarte via ODBC con ese objeto son esos?

Comment: En realidad no, me guie de este video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aF552bMEcO4&list=PLkVDWB4yiY6ef4SeIjakn173NziYG7PJG&index=8&t=130s

Comment: Deberias estar usando algo asi: conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=mynewdsn;UID=user;PWD=password') mira la documentacion de ese compenente [aca](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows)